# Regarding as-path-access-list

Tags: bgp

On the given router, my objective is to configure as-path-access-list so it doesn’t accept any prefixes originated by AS 1.
Below are the command outputs:

```
Coarse#sho ip bgp
BGP table version is 7, local router ID is 44.44.44.44
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 1.1.1.0/24       192.168.34.3                           0 3 2 1 i
*> 3.3.3.0/24       192.168.34.3             0             0 3 i
*> 4.4.4.0/24       0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
*> 11.11.11.0/24    192.168.34.3                           0 3 2 1 i
*> 33.33.33.0/24    192.168.34.3             0             0 3 i
*> 44.44.44.0/24    0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
```

Now i need to match all prefixes originated in AS 1,

```
Coarse#sho ip bgp regexp 1$
BGP table version is 7, local router ID is 44.44.44.44
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 1.1.1.0/24       192.168.34.3                           0 3 2 1 i
*> 11.11.11.0/24    192.168.34.3                           0 3 2 1 i
```

Configuring this as-path-access-list

```
Coarse#sho ip as-path-access-list 1
AS path access list 1
    deny 1$

Coarse#sho run | sec router bgp
router bgp 4
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 4.4.4.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 network 44.44.44.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 neighbor 192.168.14.1 remote-as 1
 neighbor 192.168.14.1 filter-list 1 in
 neighbor 192.168.34.3 remote-as 3
 no auto-summary
Coarse#
```

But still i see that, these prefixes (originated from AS 1) are present in  BGP table

```
Coarse#sho ip bgp
BGP table version is 7, local router ID is 44.44.44.44
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 1.1.1.0/24       192.168.34.3                           0 3 2 1 i
*> 3.3.3.0/24       192.168.34.3             0             0 3 i
*> 4.4.4.0/24       0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
*> 11.11.11.0/24    192.168.34.3                           0 3 2 1 i
*> 33.33.33.0/24    192.168.34.3             0             0 3 i
*> 44.44.44.0/24    0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
```

Can you please guide where i went wrong?

Comment: You've attached filter-list to wrong peer. It's supposed to be neighbor 192.168.34.3 filter-list 1 in instead of neighbor 192.168.14.1 filter-list 1 in.

Comment: You should also change regex from 1$ to _1$. Without the underscore you deny all prefixies originated in AS(s) which last digit is 1. Like 61, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving your routes from 192.168.34.3, so you need to apply the filter list on that neighbor, instead of 192.168.14.1.